# No Default API Levels in AVD Manager

Tags: android, sdk

I installed the Android SDK and also installed the ADT Plugin for Eclipse.
When I launched the AVD manager, I don't see a default API Level in it. I clicked on New and in the Create New AVD Window the Target is always Disabled. I am not able to start over because of this.

System Specifications:
Eclipse : 3.7
Android SDK is 20.1 or something i am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open SDK Manager and install the android version apis.
See the screenshot.

[image]